# What is an origin header and where do I insert Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: html, header, access-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use Access-Control-Allow-Origin? Does it just go in between the html head tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015782/how-do-i-use-access-control-allow-origin-does-it-just-go-in-between-the-html-hea)

I'm trying to allow cross domain requests, but I don't know where to put Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  Does it go in the html request file or index.html?   I put this code in my html request file, don't laugh at me if this is way off.

```
<head>
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</head>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` can't go inside the head tags, it is an html header so it belongs in php script.

Comment: It is an HTTP header, not an HTML header. There are many ways to set it, PHP is just one.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Example - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control Server-Side Access Control (CORS)