# TypeError: Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. only in Safari 11

Tags: javascript, typescript, safari, cors

```
 try {
     await this.GFontToDataURI('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' + label.fontfamily)
             .then(cssRules => {
                         style2.innerHTML += cssRules.join('\n');
                });
            }
  catch (ex) {
}
```

Safari 11 throws the error (other browsers not):

```
TypeError: Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

I use this function: [How to use Google fonts in Canvas when Drawing DOM objects in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402584/how-to-use-google-fonts-in-canvas-when-drawing-dom-objects-in-svg/42405731#42405731)

Comment: be sure the problem isn't this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10752078/3263519

Comment: this isn't the problem. I load a google font from google service as you can see in the url

Comment: Is this [my GFontToDataURI function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42405731/3702797)? If so, first of, sorry for providing so bad code... But I warned it's just a *proof of concept*. Nevertheless, even though the example doesn't work in stacksnippets null-origined iframe, it does on [https jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mdsb6vL/) and [http jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mdsb6vL/).

Comment: yes. that is the function. It works well in other browsers

Comment: @HikmatGurbanli's comment still applies, are you executing it from the `file://` protocol? It does matter.

Comment: No I am executing from a webserver

Answer (score -1):

crossorigin is allowed by http so you could change https to http.

or if you want to allow cross origin requests for https you need to set the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin

[How do I use Access-Control-Allow-Origin? Does it just go in between the html head tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015782/how-do-i-use-access-control-allow-origin-does-it-just-go-in-between-the-html-he)

Comment: since I access google fonts this isn't possible for me

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try to fetch the font with regular `fetch` request?
I have checked in safari and everything seems to work fine.

```
fetch("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Helvetica")
  .then(res => console.log(res.text()))
```

Comment: does this also work with woff2 files? e.g. https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lobstertwo/v10/BngMUXZGTXPUvIoyV6yN5-fN5qU.woff2   , sorry I have no mac to test

Comment: I can't see a difference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402584/how-to-use-google-fonts-in-canvas-when-drawing-dom-objects-in-svg/42405731#42405731