# How to Connect to a Time Server JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time, server

I am trying to conenct to any external server in order to display server time instead of the machine time in JavaScript.

I have tried reading

[How do I use Access-Control-Allow-Origin? Does it just go in between the html head tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015782/how-do-i-use-access-control-allow-origin-does-it-just-go-in-between-the-html-he)
, [Understanding XMLHttpRequest over CORS (responseText)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400594/understanding-xmlhttprequest-over-cors-responsetext/13400954#13400954)
, and [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)
but am very limited in knowledge for this subject, so am confused on how to implement the suggestions to get access to a server time.

I am still getting the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

And don't know how to fix it. This is the current code that I have:

HTML:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Server date/time</title>
    <script language="javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script language="javascript">
  document.write("Server time is: " + date);
  </script>
  <body>
  </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var xmlHttp;
function serverTime(){
    try {
        //FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (err1) {
        //IE
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch (err2) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch (err3) {
                // use CPU time.
                alert("Using CPU Time");
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open('HEAD',"https://www.stackoverflow.com",false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    xmlHttp.send('');
    return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
}

var st = serverTime();
var date = new Date(st);
```

Ideas on what I am doing wrong and what I can do to get the server time? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS - What is the motivation behind introducing preflight requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381105/cors-what-is-the-motivation-behind-introducing-preflight-requests)

Comment: @Amacado This helps me understand the reasoning behind CORS, but I am still confused on how I can fix my code to be able to get the server time?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right, but if you have no control on the remote server (like you mentioned "any server") and the remote server is blocking cors.. You basically can't.